# Getting the v, r, and s parameters using web3js or ethersjs

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

web3 documentation says that using the web3.eth.signTransaction returns the object which (inside the other object) has the r, s, and v of the message:
[image]

However, I am not getting that:

[image]

Any idea in how can I get the r, s, and v?  I want to use if to the permit function of the Dai contract

Answer (score 1):

okay figured it out:

Code below:

```
let alchemy_provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider("PROVIDE_NETWORK_NAME", "PROVIDE_YOUR_API_KEY");
let wallet = new ethers.Wallet("PROVIDE_PRIVATE_KEY", provider);

let tx = {
        to: "0x4337a3876c1a021762F8eDf16524ad09eF9F5166",
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.02")
      };

const signTx = async () => {
  signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(tx);
  console.log("SIGNEDTX", signedTx)
  console.log("PARSED TRANSACTION", ethers.utils.parseTransaction(signedTx));}

signTx();
// PARSED TRANSACTION {
  nonce: 0,
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0x4337a3876c1a021762F8eDf16524ad09eF9F5166',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x470de4df820000', _isBigNumber: true },
  data: '0x',
  chainId: 0,
  v: 27,
  r: '0x18b29ac493e5de71706f9b32a065aec46c1b3d1ee4b14b38d137e15dad1f68bc',
  s: '0x4292c664145d5952ef7cce0ba4f67da423b6c96e67713b2bf9189f8b925bb0b3',
  from: '0x4337a3876c1a021762F8eDf16524ad09eF9F5166',
  hash: '0xfccb4d5b6018401b5311065d5a22eaba7b5a6b8c1d4aa0530b8e1d17dab39f3c'
}
```

Thanks to @ricmoo [https://github.com/ricmoo] for his answer over here [https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/969#issuecomment-662884180]